# Using sqlite3 sqlcipher DB, how to? (ios)

Tags: ios, database, encryption, sqlite

I encrypted sqlite db using sqlcipher.
But how do i continue with regular work with the db?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't [the documentation](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/) help?

I think you should do something like:

```
const char* key = [@"BIGSecret" UTF8String];
sqlite3_key(database, key, strlen(key));
if (sqlite3_exec(database, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"db password ok");
        //perform operation

} else {
        NSLog(@"db password mismatch");
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: btw, I'm using obj-c, but I think you got the idea.